# Sort figures by order of reference

Tags: table-of-contents

I am writing a manuscript and I have many figures I will place in a Supplementary Information section (SI). I will be referencing each of the figures, but I do not know ahead of time the order I will be referencing them. I would like the figures in the SI to be ordered by order of reference in the main text. For example if I do

```
... something something figure \ref{fig_smile} something something figure \ref{fig_frown} ...
```

then I would want the figure with a smile to appear before the figure with a frown in the SI.

Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: What is "SI"?

Comment: @Mico most likely supporting/supplementary information, i.e., an appendix.

Answer (score 1):

An approach with LuaLaTeX. The idea is to store each label in an ordered Lua array when it is encountered in a `\ref` statement, and store the code for each figure in an associative array with the label as key. After all labels and figures are stored a loop over the ordered label array outputs the figures into the document.

To make the syntax a bit easier and to avoid modifying `\ref`, the MWE below defines a new command `\siref` that stores the label using the Lua function `table.insert` in the `reflist` array and then calls `\ref` itself.

Furthermore a command `\sifigure` is defined with two arguments, the label and the figure code. This command stores the code in the Lua array `imglist` with the label as key. The code is passed to the array using `\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#2}}` to make sure that backslashes the the figure code are escaped while avoiding expansion until the code is actually passed back to the document in the for loop.

The Lua code itself contains just the two list variables and a function with the for loop. Within the loop the figure environment and the label are added. This could be simplified further by putting all the figure code in the argument of `\sifigure`, in that case the loop just becomes `tex.sprint(imglist[lbl])`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
reflist = {}
imglist = {}

function printlist()
   for _, lbl in ipairs(reflist) do
      tex.sprint("\\begin{figure}[h]" .. imglist[lbl] .. "\\label{" .. lbl .. "}\\end{figure}")
   end
end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand{\siref}[1]{%
\directlua{table.insert(reflist, "#1")}\ref{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\sifigure}[2]{%
\directlua{imglist["#1"] = "\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#2}}"}%
}

\begin{document}
... something something figure \siref{fig_smile} something something figure \siref{fig_frown} ... something something figure \siref{fig_surprise} ...

\section*{Supplementary Information}
\sifigure{fig_frown}{\centering\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}\caption{First in source}}
\sifigure{fig_smile}{\centering\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\caption{Second in source}}
\sifigure{fig_surprise}{\centering\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}\caption{Third in source}}

\directlua{printlist()}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that if a label is added that already exists then the figure is printed twice and a duplicate label warning is generated. You could use a normal `\ref` instead of `\siref` for the second and further reference, or write a bit of extra Lua code to check if a label is already present in `reflist` (surprisingly, Lua does not seem to have a built-in array membership function).